# How can I JOIN a VIEW to a TABLE based on unique values?

Tags: sql-server, join, view, sql-insert, uniqueidentifier

How can I join a VIEW to a TABLE based on unique values?  Background information: a CSV file is downloaded from a web browser containing customer information, including shipping addresses and order numbers.  The order numbers are our unique identifiers.  The CSV file will contain duplicate information that we've already imported earlier.  We want to prevent the duplicates from coming into our main table.

The CSV file is difficult to work with to directly import into SQL so it requires some Excel work to get it prepared by inserting double quotes in each data field for the import.  The import goes into a table - the dbo.staging with double quotes for each data field. Every import will delete the existing rows.

Then, it goes into a view (dbo.cleandata) removing double quotes. Every import will delete the existing rows. We now have clean data.

From the view, we now want to append every NEW order to the main table (dbo.main), and NOT add the existing order data to the main table. This is where I am stuck. How do I write data from the view, dbo.cleandata, into dbo.main where order number does not exist in table dbo.main? The below query does not give me the results we desire.  Any suggestions?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[main] ([bill-to-name]
      ,[order-number]
      ,[ship-to-name]
      ,[ship-to-address1]
      ,[ship-to-city]
      ,[ship-to-state]
      ,[ship-to-zip])
SELECT A.[bill-to-name]
      ,A.[order-number]
      ,A.[ship-to-name]
      ,A.[ship-to-address1]
      ,A.[ship-to-city]
      ,A.[ship-to-state]
      ,A.[ship-to-zip]
  FROM [$dsp].[dbo].[cleandata] as A
 JOIN
  [main] on [main].[order-number] = A.[order-number]
WHERE [main].[order-number] <> A.[order-number]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[main] ([bill-to-name]
      ,[order-number]
      ,[ship-to-name]
      ,[ship-to-address1]
      ,[ship-to-city]
      ,[ship-to-state]
      ,[ship-to-zip])
SELECT A.[bill-to-name]
      ,A.[order-number]
      ,A.[ship-to-name]
      ,A.[ship-to-address1]
      ,A.[ship-to-city]
      ,A.[ship-to-state]
      ,A.[ship-to-zip]
  FROM [$dsp].[dbo].[cleandata] as A
LEFT JOIN [main] on [main].[order-number] = A.[order-number]
WHERE [main].[order-number] IS NULL;
```